# How to preserve modification time when uploading a file with JSch put to SFTP server

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

In `sftp` you may use `put -p` to preserve the last modification timestamp. How can I do that in Java using JSch?

I use the function `put(source, destination, mode)`, but cannot find a value of `mode` similar to `-p` in `sftp`.

A current timestamp is put on the file at the destination. I want the timestamp from the source.

Answer (score 1):

JSch won't do it for you. You have to explicitly update the remote timestamp after the upload using [`ChannelSftp.setMtime`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#setMtime-java.lang.String-int-).